# Find the Number of Elements of a Particular Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Find the size of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]/I$, where $I=(18+\sqrt{-19}, 7)$.

The standard way to proceed would be  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]/I=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+19, 18+x, 7)=\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^2+5, x+4)$.

At this step i want to say that once I substitute $x=-4$ and note that $x^2+5=21=0\mod 7$, our quotient ring has size 7 and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7$. How to justify this final step?

Comment: [The Third Isomorphism Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem)

Comment: $(x^2\!+\!19,x\!+\!18,\color{#c00}7)\overset{\large \rm mod\ \color{#c00}7}= (\color{#0a0}x^2\!-\!2,\color{#0a0}{x\!-\!3},7)\overset{\large \rm mod\ \color{#0a0}{x-3}}=(\color{#0a0}3^2\!-\!2,x\!-\!3,7)=(x\!-\!3,7)\tag*{}$ $\tag*{}$ then apply the 3rd Isomorphism Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_7[x]}{(x^2+5, x+4)}\simeq\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x+4)}{{(x^2+5, x+4)}/(x+4)}\simeq\dfrac{\mathbb Z_7}{(21)}=\dfrac{\mathbb Z_7}{(0)}\simeq\mathbb Z_7$$

(I have used the following isomorphism: $R[X]/(X+a)\simeq R$ for any $a\in R$. This isomorphism is induced by the evaluation homomorphism $\phi:R[X]\to R$, $\phi(X)=-a$.)